# SharedPreferences: how to clear all preferences when application crashes

Tags: android, crash, sharedpreferences

im new in android and im using SharedPreference of android for storing some states of the buttons, lets say storing the active state and unactive state of the button in SharedPreferences. But problems occurs whenever my application crashes, i want to clear my all preferences (i.e. making the button state on default value).

so i was wondering that is there any way i can clear my app's preferences whenever my application crashes.

Thanks

Comment: @GrIsHu that's not true. SharedPreferences are stored in a file and this file is deleted when you uninstall the application or force a data clear

Comment: It's better to use Application class if you want data gone on App crash.

Comment: @Dhaval I don't see how using the Application class would help in the case of an app crash due to an uncaught Exception ...

Comment: @2Dee Yeah, but the man wants the state of values cleared on crash which won't be achievable from Shared preferences. I know that application class doesn't have such purpose, but as a tweak it can work. Albeit, you are right about some uncaught Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, when an application crashes, it means an exception that has not been caught happened. If you're not catching this exception, you cannot do any action.

Try to analyse the cause of the crash and fix it rather than relying on crashing as a normal course of action.

Comment: what about unchecked exception ?

Comment: @blackbelt What about it?

Comment: My point was: crashes happen because you have not handled something. It may be a bug, a system access problem, etc. Crashes are something you didn't expect (not to confuse with exceptions in general).

Comment: if application is killed by OS, is there any way to clear preferences when application is killed?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to re-write your app so it doesn't crash, an app crash is a **terrible** user experience ! Then handle the SharedPreferences is a safer way ...

Answer (score 0):

use the app-info of your app and clear cache or all the data!